# EmberJS: Ember data binding oneWay in components

Tags: ember.js

I'm using emberjs and I would like to achieve a one way binding on some properties in my component.

Is there any way to set directly to a property to be one way binding in a component without creating a new property of that?

For example I want to avoid doing this:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
   name: null,
   _name: Ember.computed.oneWay('name')
});
```

Comment: I guess no. When ever you pass `name` property to other component , you can make use of `readOnly` helper some thing like this `{{comp-a name=(readonly name) }}`

Comment: This looks very helpful. I knew only about the mut and the unbound helpers but those didn't help me at all.

Comment: @kumkanillam Can you please post you answer not as a comment so I can make it as an answer of my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `readOnly` [helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_readOnly) It provides read only one way binding.
So whenever you pass `name` property to component, then make use of this `readOnly` helper to avoid two way binding.

`{{comp-a name=(readonly name) }}`

Comment: As mentioned in above comments this solve my problem. Thanks.